# Weird $3^n$ in an identity to be combinatorially proved

Tags: combinatorics

Give a combinatorial proof of the following identity:

$$3^n=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}2^{n-i}$$

I can't see any counting argument that would yield $3^n$, and the right hand side is also pretty opaque. For some reason I really really suck at doing these proofs - I just started my first combinatorics course.

Comment: This is the [Newton binomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) for $(2+1)^n$

Comment: just take out $2^n$ and use Binomial theorem

Comment: I want a *combinatorics* proof which means no algebraic rearranging of the stuff.

Comment: @EricDong It might help to modify your question as "I want a proof by a *combinatorial argument*" to get better responses.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose you have $n$ balls to be put into 3 boxes. You may keep any or all boxes empty.Then the number of ways of putting $n$ balls into 3 boxes is $3^n$. 
For the right hand side of the equation, you may fix a box $C$. The box $C$ may contain $0,1,2,\dots n$ balls. If the box $C$ has $i$ balls, you may choose the $i-\text{balls}$ to be put into $C$ in $\binom{n}{i}$ ways and the remaining $n-i$ balls may be put into boxes A or B in $2^{n-i}$ ways. Hence the number of ways of putting $n$ balls into 3 boxes is $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}2^{n-i}$ ways and hence $$3^n=\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}2^{n-i}.$$ Please let me know if my solution is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$$(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}b^k$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Color $n$ balls with 3 colors.